# php functions with query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am learning php and currently working with functions.
Created a simple database with two tables: Category and News.

Also I created three functions: get_news_title, get_news_image, get_news_text
Each function returns - title, image or full article text.
Right now it is setup like this:

```
function get_news_title($id) {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT title from news WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $title = $row["title"];
}

function get_news_image($id) {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT img from news WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $img = $row["img"];
}

function get_news_text($id) {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT full_text from news WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $text = $row["full_text"];
}
```

Every function contains a query, but is there maybe a better way? Is it good practice to use query in every single function. Because if I call all of these functions then there are three separate queries run.

And would it be a good idea to use something like this:

```
function get_news($id,$field) {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT :field from news WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
    $sql->bindparam(":field", $field);
    $sql->execute();
    $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $title = $row["title"];
}
```

Comment: You cannot use parameters for column names. Reason: How would the query be compiled, optimized and an execution plan created if the database does not know the Column or table etc that it is supposed to be using

Comment: Why not have one function that executes a query that gets all 3 columns in one go `SELECT title, news, full_text from news WHERE id = :id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I could do that, but for learning purpose I am doing it this way. Is there a way to execute query in one function and then call fields in other from the query?

Comment: did you see my answer? what's missing? comment it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this if you want to stick to your approach and you are sure that $fields is only controlled by you:

```
     function get_news($id,array $fields) {

        $fields = implode(',', $fields);

        $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT $fields from news WHERE id = :id");
        $sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
        $sql->execute();
        $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $title = $row["title"];
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but make sure to check @RiggsFolly 's answer regarding security!

Answer (score 0):

Its a strange thing to want to do, but as you say its a learning exercise it is quite simple to pass a parameter that is the column name you want to select.

```
function get_news_column($id, $columnname) {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT $columnname from news WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindparam(":id", $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $title = $row["title"];
}


// called like this

$title = get_news_column($id, 'Title');
$img = get_news_column($id, 'img');
$full_text = get_news_column($id, 'full_text');
```

> I would suggest you add some error checking as doing this it is also quite simple to pass a column name that does not exists and would make the query fail.
>
> This would be dangerous if the column name you were passing was being retrieved from a user input i.e. $_POST or $_GET fields.

Comment: what's different to my answer instead your's is only supporting one column name?

Comment: Well only that which you mention really. But the OP seems to want to get only one column at a time. Like I said in the answer, its an odd thing to want to do as it will more than triple the execution time to get the 3 columns this way.

Comment: hm, but OP is asking whether it isn't an issue if 3 queries are run - and yes, so I wanted to give a way to ask for 1-3 fields with only one query. but ok.

Comment: @LBA Its unlikely that either of us will get an UV or anything else from this, so its probably simpler to just move on and find another question